# PHP Create a yearly automated schedule

Tags: php, calendar, schedule

I'm trying to create a yearly automated schedule for a publication. Every issue has 3 dates (Wednesday, Friday & Monday), that occur every two weeks. And in some cases when the day falls on a holiday it should automatically adjust and goto the following day.

I'm trying to do this all right now in PHP, I've got most of it working but after issue 7 the script goes wrong and seems to skip a week. Can anyone help or suggest a way of achieving this?

Here is pseudo-code of my logic;

```
For 12 months
    Get the amount of days in a given month
        For days in a month
            If Wednesday
        assign date to a var
            Else if Friday
                assign date to a var
                print wednesday var
                print friday var
                print monday var
                increment counter in order to skip ahead to the next week
            Else if Monday
                assign date to a var
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to know the number of days in the month? If publication is every two weeks, the actual month is irrelevant - it's simply two weeks after the last issue.

Comment: You would save us quite some time if you posted the PHP code as well, since you already have it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should point you in the right direction (untested, but should do what you want).

```
$iYear = date('Y');

for($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) {
  $iNumDaysInMonth = date('t', mktime(0,0,0,$i,1,$iYear);

  for($j = 1; $j <= $iNumDaysInMonth; $j++) {
    $iDayNum = date('N', mktime(0,0,0,$i,$j,$iYear));

    if($iDayNum == 3) {
      // wednesday
    } elseif($iDayNum == 5) {
      // friday
    } elseif($iDayNum == 1) {
      // monday
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This quite similar to what I have already. The only thing missing is the increment of every two weeks. Is there a way to offset the count by 2 weeks? Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should increase $j with 14 at the point where you want it. (`$j += 14;`)

Comment: Thanks! I'm marking this correct, I found another way to do it without incrementing by 14. I used a if statement with a boolean to switch the print statement off/on, that way I only print to screen the three dates every 2 weeks... it works! Thanks again.

Comment: Working with datetime objects will make your life a whole lot easier.

Comment: True, but I provided an answer in relation to his question and psuedo-code.